# Respond to Descendent Class PropertyChanged Event

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a class, BaseSample, that uses another class, MainData, as one of its fields:

```
Protected _sampleData As MainData

Public Property SampleData() As MainData

    Get

        Return _sampleData

    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As MainData)

        _sampleData = value

    End Set


End Property
```

MainData in turn has a collection of a class, ProcessData, as a field and ProcessData has a collection of a class, Measurement, as a field.  I.e.:

> MainData
>
> ```
> |- IEnumerable (Of ProcessData)
>
>     |- IEnumerable (Of Measurement)
> ```

These classes are entities in a LINQ to SQL file.  In the Measurement class, I raise the PropertyChanged event when the CrucibleOxidizedMass property changes:

```
Private Sub OnCrucibleOxidizedMassChanged()

    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("CrucibleOxidizedMass"))

End Sub
```

In the BaseSample class, I want to respond to the CrucibleOxidizedMass PropertyChanged event in any of the descendent Measurment instances.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through all ProcessDates and for each one iterate through each Measurement and subscribe to the event.

In C# code:

```
foreach(var processData in value.ProcessDatas)
{
    foreach(var measurement in processData.Measurements)
    {
        measurement.PropertyChanged += OnMeasurementPropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Be sure to unsubscribe from those events, when new sample data is set. Also, you probably should unsubscribe from individual events when either a measurement is removed from a `ProcessData` or when a `ProcessData` is removed from the `SampleData`.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, Daniel. Your answer lead me to the solution for my problem.